# How to filter a model queryset before it renders

Tags: django, date, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to run the view below in my django website:

```
class CalendarView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Class
    template_name = 'leads/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # use today's date for the calendar
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
```

However, when I add the below code, it does not filter the model `Class` before rendering the calendar. Therefore, I end up going through all of the instances in the `Class` model.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return Class.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(1111,11,11))
```

Of course, I am going to edit the function above to use the user's information instead of just filtering for the date 1111-11-11.

However, if this is not possible, I hope you guys know a way to pass the user's information to utils.py to work my way around the problem. I need something like below(`self.request.user`) that was used for views.py:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_student:
        queryset = Lead.objects.filter(
            status__exact="n"
        )
    return context
```

It would be really helpful if you guys can help me out, and ask me any questions. Thanks.

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
</div>

{{ calendar }}

{% endblock %}
```

By the way, `Calendar` in my views is linked to the utils.py. Here is a part of utils.py I am having trouble with:

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Class.objects.filter(date__year=self.year, date__month=self.month).exclude(student=None)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

I want to filter the `events` variable depending on which user is using the website. As you can see right now, it is not dynamic.

Comment: add your template , i dont see any error in your view and queryset , but your model as name "Class" ? very bad name

Comment: I added the template. Yeah, I know its not the best, but I already started with that name, so I don't really have an option of changing it at this point.

Comment: yout dont use your list in template ?

Comment: I added a part of the utils.py I am having trouble with. I actually borrowed this code from another website after research, but I think the utils.py is where all the html is happening.

Comment: ok so you need to replace the event in your claendar class by the queryset in your view ?

Comment: well... I am planning to use a lot of if statements such as `if user.is_student` to change the queryset in according to the type of user.

Comment: @coderDcoder  Ever figure this one out?  I'm trying to do something similar.